# Efficiency of H production from FeOOH catalyst?

Tags: energy, hydrogen, catalysis, hydrolysis

Research has recently found that FeOOH is 25 times better at hydrogen production than titanium dioxide.

Today, a new electrolysis plant delivers energy efficiency of around 80%. Is 25x the Honda-Fujishima reaction, using FeOOH higher efficiency than that?

ref:
https://www.tus.ac.jp/en/mediarelations/archive/20200227001.html

Comment: I have read the article. I am not convinced. They say that by irradiating "something" with a Hg-Xe lamp, and using rust as catalyst, plus some oxygen, they produce more H2 than with another catalyst (TiO2). Well. Catalytic effect of rust has been studied for years, with or without light, without any important result. They say that adding Oxygen would improve the yield. Why ? On the contrary, Oxygen should have the inverse effect.

Comment: Can't any chemist check their finding with some rust, some methanol and a xenon lamp? it sounds like a 1 hour experiement. It would be crazy for any magazine to publish something so easy to verify if it is silly and easy to verify.

Comment: Does iron oxyhydroxide really assists in production of *monoatomic* hydrogen (the title says "H")?